# Is there a possibility in rename the files of a html fileinput prior to posting

Tags: javascript, html, http, post, file-io

I have a HTML form with various fields and some fileinputs.
The problem is, that the webserver runs on a windows machine, and some users upload file from mac os or linux with charachters not allowed on windwos, such as: **:** and **?**.

The filehandler (Axon.Ivy / JAVA) which fetches the files cannot work with theses charachters and throws an exception. I have no possibility to change the filehandler.

Since the orignal filenames are irrelevant, my optimal solution would be, to rename the files, or manipulate the filename attribute in the POST data before the actual POST happens. Preferrably with javascript.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData), you can set an other name to your files before sending it through AJAX :

```js
...
var form = new FormData();
form.append(someField, someInput.value);
// when appending a File or a Blob, the third param is the name of the File
form.append('fileField', fileinput.files[0], filename);
xhr.send(form);
```

```js
sub.onclick = e => {
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('fileField', inp.files[0], 'myFile.ext');
  console.log(form.get('fileField'));
  }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
<button id="sub">submit</button>
```

Comment: do you have any information about browser compatibility. MDN has only the following information: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData
Furthermore I would prefer a solution without AJAX.

Comment: @Dethrall, I always thought that even IE10 did support the filename param, but now MDN gives me a doubt (note that on the [`#append` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Browser_compatibility) it's set to '?' for IE). But as I understood your issue, it's not a problem for windows system anyway.

Comment: it's not an issue for windows users, because they have the same restriction to filenames as the server. However, I do not want to handle different browsers or OS's differently.

Comment: @Dethrall and what is your minimal browser's support ? If <=IE10, then it's fine, in worse case, it won't change the filename of files coming from IE, but all others will be fine.

Comment: I need to support IE <= 10. Your solution would work, thank you for that! My problem is though, that I would have to redesign the whole serverside which I do not have time for.

Comment: @Dethrall, I don't see why you would need to change anything server-side. You obviously already sent these files as multipart/FormData if you had problems with file names. For the server, it should make no difference. (don't forget to change `"fileField"` to whatever was the name of your file input).